# Is there any way to disable Cart functionality in Magento for specific days of week?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

I want users to not be able to order on weekends.

And for that i want to disable Cart functionality on my website for specific days.

Is there a way to do that in Magento?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to do so. It would make more sense to just not send ordered items until Monday. If they find they can't order on your site, they may go elsewhere.

Comment: In this case it is for food delivery, such as weekend service is not active!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an override to both:

> /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

AND

> /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

For indexAction on both add a strtotime call to get the day of the week and if its the weekend redirect back with a session message stating that checkout is unavailable on weekends.

Could also be done with an observer on both route calls detecting day of the week.

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you be a little more detailed what to do. I do not understand many of PHP, only know how to modify it. I will be thankful to write the code that is needed.